# change position of element using hook

Tags: hooks

I am using Storefront (Woocommerce theme).

I created a child theme.

I want to move the secondary navigation below the main menu.

I added this to functions.php to the child theme but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
<?php

remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 52 );

?>
```

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745795/change-order-of-items-in-storefront-theme-header

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a replacement for the support channels of plugins and themes. This question should be referred to the author of the theme. The only valid way to ask "how to modify a plugin/theme" kind of questions is by including the relevant code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding and removing the hooks like this.
You should do the work on some action/hook. which gets fire before these hooks.

so you can call it in this way

```
add_action( 'init' , 'sf_change_header_position' , 10 );
function sf_change_header_position() {
   remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
   add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 52 );
}
```